# WPDB update row with != in where clause

Tags: wpdb, sql

I'm using wpdb to develop a plugin to add a custom form to wordpress. To update a row, I use an array and `wpdb->update()`. WP Class Reference says:

> My SQL code should be something like `UPDATE ROW .... WHERE a='a' AND b!='c'`.

The problem is that `!=` doesn't seem to be working, in fact from [WP Class Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows)

> A named array of `WHERE` clauses (in column => value pairs).

I need to connect to an external database and fetch data from that database so I can't use any of the available plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is exmaple code,You will change as per your requirement

```
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
    SET post_parent = 7
    WHERE ID = 15 
        AND post_status = 'static'
    "
);
```

Comment: The problem being wpdb::query doesn't return affected rows like wpdb::update does.